# Is $x^5+x^4-2x+2$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Is $x^5+x^4-2x+2$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

I think it is but I am only capable of showing that it has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: rational root theorem says that if it did have rational roots they would be $\in \{\pm1,\pm 2\}$

Comment: How did you show it has no roots?

Comment: The polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_3[X]$, hence also irreducible over $\mathbb Q[X]$ , but I did not prove that by hand, I only found it out with PARI/GP, a calculator program.

Comment: Showing that $f$ has no rational roots should be enough if take into account a [generalization of Eisenstein Criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2155193/generalized-eisensteins-criterion-over-integral-domains).

Answer (score 4):

This polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbf Z$, hence over $\mathbf Q$ because it is irreducible over $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$, for the following reasons:

- It has no root in  $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z=\{0, 1,-1\}$, so it has no linear factor.
- So if it has an irreducible (non trivial) factor, it has a *quadratic* irreducible factor.
- Now the irreducible quadratic polynomials  in $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z[x]$ are 
  $$\{x^2+1, x^2+x-1, x^2-x-1\}$$
  (These are the only quadratic polynomials which have no root.)
- Performing the division of the given polynomial by each of these quadratic polynomials yields as a remainder $\; -x$, $1$, $1$ respectively.

Thus the polynomial has no linear nor quadratic irreducible factor, hence is irreducible.